# pass a variable from a function to parent scope using promises or any other suitable way of doing it

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I pass the value of var flower from inside `form.parse()` into `response.write()` so that I can output it?

Answers to similar questions suggest using promises however if that's the way to do it I would appreciate some help in how to apply a promise in this case

```
var formidable = require("formidable");
function upload(response, request) {
       var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
       form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file, flower) {
            file.path = './uploads/' + file.name;
            var flowerImage = file.name ;
       });

      form.parse(request,  function(error, fields, files ) {
      });

      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write("image name is " + flowerImage);
      response.end();
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: managed to solve by thinking about it in a different way and rephrasing the question and got some help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246875/how-to-pass-the-node-response-stream-object-into-an-event-handler-function?noredirect=1#comment50492233_31246875

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the response on the Callback itself

```
function upload(response, request) {

       var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

       form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file, flower) {
            file.path = './uploads/' + file.name;
            var flowerImage = file.name ;
            this.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            this.write("image name is " + flowerImage);
            this.end();
       }.bind(response));

  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried this. For some reason it cannot access the response object from inside the form.on() function, I thought n javascript variables can access values in the parent function but it doesn't seem to be doing it here...

Comment: take a look to the update, I used the `Function.prototype.bind` method to set the response as the context of the callback

Comment: thanks.. I got really excited about this answer but I'm still not able to get the variable into the response object although I must be getting closer..

Comment: I reworded the question and reposted using your answer and it is solved now - thanks for you help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246875/how-to-pass-the-node-response-stream-object-into-an-event-handler-function?noredirect=1#comment50492233_31246875

Answer (score 0):

declare the `var flowerImage` next not the `var form`

**EDIT**: My bad... flowerImage is created using an async call...
This has been answered many times.

See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: are you saying I should use promises? Any advice in how to implement one in this case ?