# How to pass the node response stream object into an event handler function?

Tags: node.js

I want to know  how to get the response node stream object passed into form.on() So that the name of the file that has been uploaded will appear on the screen.

```
 var formidable = require("formidable");

 function upload(response, request) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();


        form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file, flower) {
        file.path = './uploads/' + file.name;
        var flowerImage = file.name ;
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("image name is " + flowerImage);
        response.end();

       });

}
```

Comment: Have you simply tried using `response`? It seems like it should be accessible, since your `form.on` listener function is lexically inside `upload`.

Comment: yes i tries it as above, ignore the flower parameter , that's not there, I don't know eh it doesn't work, someone suggested using promises but I didn't understand how

Comment: Your code should work. If your code has a problem, it's not a problem with accessing the `response` variable. How are you calling `upload`? Are you sure that `response ` is the object you think it is?

Comment: Are you passing the right arguments to your `upload()` function? Currently you have `response, request` whereas the typical convention is `request, response`. Perhaps you have the values swapped?

Comment: Its passed using a router I copied from node beginner tutorial https://github.com/manuelkiessling/nodebeginner.org/tree/master/code/application  My function is added to the upload function in requestHandlers.js

Comment: you are right! I moved the form processing up to the router then passed the file name down to the 'upload' function which no only prints out the file name which is perfect!